# square sum function catalan

Tags: calculus

I could not show directly the following result it is posible calculate numerically it seem work fine
$$\sum _{k=1}^\infty  \frac{r_2(k)}{k^2}=\frac{2 \pi ^2 \mathrm{Catalan} }{3}$$

Comment: And what is $r_2(k)$?

Comment: @zhoraster:I guess it's the [sum of two squares function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html),is that right Antonio?

Comment: @Nicco, probably you are right. I'm getting just $\pi$ though in this case, so something must be wrong with my approach.

Comment: @Zhoraster:what's your approach?

Comment: @Nicco, never mind, it was wrong. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that $r_2(k)$ is the [sum of squares function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html). It is known that
$$
r_2(k) = 4\sum_{\text{odd }m \,|\, k} (-1)^{(m-1)/2}.$$
Then 
$$
\sum _{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{r_2(k)}{k^2} = 4\sum _{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{\text{odd }m \,|\, k} \frac{(-1)^{(m-1)/2} }{k^2} =  4\sum_{\text{odd }m}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{(m-1)/2} }{(nm)^2}\\ = 4\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{j} }{(2j+1)^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1 }{n^2} = 4 G \zeta(2) = \frac{2\pi^2 G}{3},
$$
as required.